# Java Access Abstract Instance variables

Tags: java, abstract-class, member-variables

I have an `abstract class` with a variable like follows:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {

    int myVariable = 1;

    protected abstract void FunctionThatUsesMyVariable();
}
```

Then when I go to instantiate my `class` through the following code, `myVariable` cannot be seen:

```
MyAbstractClass myClass = new MyAbstractClass() {

    @Override
    protected void FunctionThatUsesMyVariable() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
};
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are declaring `myVariable` as having package access and your 2 classes reside in different packages. Thus the variable is not visible to inheriting classes. You can declare it with `protected` access to be visible or put the 2 classes in the same package.

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {

    protected int myVariable = 1;

    protected abstract void FunctionThatUsesMyVariable();
}
```

Comment: That is only true if the two classes are in different packages.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is correct. Just one more question. `myVariable` is a `File` and now it complains about `the local variable may not have been initialized` but the constructor does initialise it? If I did that in a normal class it would not complain, why is it here?

Comment: Post the exact the code of the two classes and indicate the line where the compiler complains. But I think it should be another question.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work for me:

```
public class Test {
  public static abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    int myVariable = 1;
    protected abstract void FunctionThatUsesMyVariable();
  }

  public void test() {
    MyAbstractClass myClass = new MyAbstractClass() {
      @Override
      protected void FunctionThatUsesMyVariable() {
        myVariable = 2;
      }
    };
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Test().test();
  }
}
```

I suspect you are declaring the two classes in different packages. If that is what you want then you should make the variable `protected` (or `public` if you must). Alternatively - obviously - put them in the same package.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your variable as protected. It's `package-private` by default.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're still subclassing/extending the abstract class and unless you make it protected, the field isn't inherited.